# document.fileSize Browser Support

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

Does any browser other than IE support document.fileSize, or the equivelant?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533752(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.fileSize` is an IE-only extension: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document. In other browsers, you could re-fetch an object with XHR and examine the `Content-Length` header of the response.

Comment: thats a little too much work, maybe all browsers should add it..is quite valuable.